# Getting noClassFoundError libcore while runing the android project

Tags: android

I am very new to android. I am developing my first application, Simple to Print Hello World.
While Running the project I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "AsyncQueryWorker" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: libcore/io/Libcore
    at android.os.Process.myTid(Process.java:670)
    at android.os.HandlerThread_Delegate.run(HandlerThread_Delegate.java:69)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: libcore.io.Libcore
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 3 more
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Give us some more details like project structure, manifest, adt version, eclipse, os :)

Comment: @BillTheLizard I know you are one of the Gurus around, i dont want to contradict you, just give my point of view:  IMHO i think it doesn't actually lack information since it is a very common problem that is self-described (the device cannot find the classes so they weren't included in the apk), and the solution is normally the same, and for that it can be useful to future users googling for the same exception, regardless of the involved library.

Comment: @CarlosRobles Ok. It was flagged for closure, so when I saw a question with just a stack trace and no code, I closed without noticing it was answered. Since you were able to answer with the information given, I'll agree and reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in **eclipse**:

**Right click in the project name** > **Properties**

then **Java Build Path** > **Order and Export**

[image]

and make sure that all the external libraries and dependencies are checked, including   **libcore**

Comment: hey thanx carlos. Now there is no exception but Android Virtual Device(AVD) is still not showing any output.?

Comment: @user3320609 If the exception is not longer there, now you have another error. Please write another question with the info about the error, and provide the code of the involved classes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added **libcore** to your classpath? If you are using Intellij IDEA (or Android Studio), just add a library dependency at the **Project Settings**